# TestgFlight Build Descriptions

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight

I am trying to set a new App Description in TestFlight (Apple) however it just ignores my input and I cannot save any changes. Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Also when it used to work you could only set this after all testers are notified. Is there a place I can amend the description before testers are notified without changing the version?

See screenshot below, note the disabled 'Save' button:
[image: Save button disabled even through new text 'Test' is added to text field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug on Apple's side. It is working well though sometimes randomly.